# Diagonalization over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I'm studying knot theory and the textbook mentions that to find the mod $p$ rank of a knot, we take a certain matrix $M$ with integer entries corresponding to the knot and diagonalize it over $\mathbb{Z}$, then count the number of entries on the resulting matrix that are $0$ mod $p$. I'm not too familiar with linear algebra -- what does it mean to diagonalize a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$ and how is this distinct for normal diagonalization (over $\mathbb{R}$)?

Comment: I'm guessing here but see [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)

Comment: What textbook exactly?

Comment: @lhf I found Livingston. It is indeed the Smith form, although not discussed as such https://www.google.com/books/edition/Knot_Theory/KXAS3KRZGRMC?hl=en&gbpv=1

Comment: https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2010_MA3F2/knot_notes.pdf  Smith form and computed examples about pages 24-30

Answer (score 0):

Its distinct. The point is that the ring of integers has just to units $\pm1$ for which inverses exist; on the other hand, e.g., $2$ is not invertible as $1/2$ is not an integers. This hampers or makes diagonalization eventually impossible.

In a field like the field of real numbers, all nonzero elements are invertible making diagonalization possible.

Comment: All entries in $M$ are taken from $\{0, 2, -1\}$. If $M$ must contain a $2$, does this mean $M$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Indeed, but maybe you could swap rows and columns to get -1 as a pivot element.

Comment: I found Livingston online. Evidently separate row and column operations are allowed. This means that we can construct the Smith Normal Form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form  which is diagonal; the condition of the diagonal elements dividing each other in order means that reduction mod p will produce a sequence of nonzero elements followed by zeros on the remainder of the main diagonal.

Comment: https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2010_MA3F2/knot_notes.pdf  Smith form about pages 24-30